# Seaborn scatterplot markers argument not working

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

### Original Plot

I am trying to plot the following graph with the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

X,y = make_blobs(n_samples=21,centers=7,shuffle=False)

palette = sns.color_palette("bright", 7)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
p1 = sns.scatterplot(X[:,0],X[:,1],palette=palette, hue=y,legend='full')
```

[image]

### The plot I failed to achieve

Now, in addition to different colors for different labels, I also want different shapes. However, even when I add the `markers` argument, nothing changes.

```
marker_list = ['.', ',', 'o', 'v', '^', '<', '>']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
p1 = sns.scatterplot(X[:,0],X[:,1],palette=palette, hue=y,legend='full',markers=marker_list)
```

[image]

Why does the `marker` argument not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the `style` grouping variable, as described in the [scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) doc. The following line should work:

```
p1 = sns.scatterplot(X[:,0],X[:,1],palette=palette, hue=y, style=y, legend='full',markers=marker_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by @rinkert, for those who do not have multiple styles (e.g. the `y` variable in the original post), you can just set `style=True` (and then also `legend=False`).

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO, and thanks for your answer! Do you have any references you can link to to help visitors learn even more about this option? If so, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74630613/edit) to include. Highest quality posts, where people learn the most, rack up more points over time as people gain knowledge to apply to their own issues, or prevent then in the first place :-) Looking forward to more great insights from you.